# how to acquire the return value of a command in ssh accessed by expect?

Tags: linux, expect

After i use expect access ssh, and run particular command in it. How could i get the actually return value of that command and set it to the return value of expect or an env variable(better)?

I am not so familiar with expect, so a few lines to show how the capture thing works would help a lot. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it the same way you would sitting at a terminal: `echo $?` (I assume your remote shell is sh/ksh/bash/...)

```tcl
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set host remote_host
set user remote_username
set prompt {\$ $}
set cmd {grep not-found /etc/passwd}

log_user 0
spawn ssh -l $user $host
expect -re $prompt

send "$cmd\r"
expect -re $prompt
send -- "echo \$?\r"
expect -re "\r\n(\\d+)\r\n.*$prompt"

set rc $expect_out(1,string)

send -- "exit\r"
expect eof

puts "return code from '$cmd' on $host = $rc"
```